# Is proliferating stem cells dangerous on some aspects?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, stem-cells

By searching on internet about replication of stem cells, I came across numerous articles speaking about how to [activate stem cell proliferation](https://blog.bioticsresearch.com/7-ways-to-promote-stem-cell-proliferation), most articles searching "natural" means for that. This looks to me as some "magical words" for speaking of a good health.

My question is: what are the benefits of activating stem cells in our body, since:

- Cicatrization mechanisms activate "when needed", when the body is underinjury
- Activating stem cells could be a cause of tumors appearance (AFAIU)?

Comment: There are lots of different types of "stem cells" in the body, with many different roles, and varying degrees of "stem-ness". That article seems to be conflating iPSCs, which are highly pluripotent, with lineage stem cells like MSCs, with progenitor cells like the ones found in the crypts of the intestines that only differentiate into one or a few different cell types. It then combines this with a lot of hand-waving about good health practices in general. Basically the take-home should be that if you live a healthy lifestyle and eat well, your body will be taken care of. Duh.

Comment: Keep in mind the source of the article, too - they sell supplements just like the kinds recommended in the text. How surprising.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understand the "buy what I sell" side of the article, but my question is about proliferating stem cells in général. About the different type of stem cells, do some of them create cancers?

Comment: They can. And, in a way, *all* cancers have some stem-like qualities to them, as they proliferate continuously, given enough nutrients, blood supply, and protection from the immune system. Some "cancer drivers" are actually mutated or dysregulated genes that are active during stem cell proliferation and division. Stem cells can grow in a cancer-like manner, but they are typically regulated by surrounding tissue and the body as a whole, so they don't form tumors. It's only when that regulation goes awry that true cancers form.

Comment: So I understand that stem cells duplication can be activated by different elements entering the organism
But besides the nutrients, is there a need for "signalling" and "planning" of how and where stem cells will duplicate? Like an organ should not grow up in all directions

Comment: Yes, there's a tremendous amount of signaling and regulation going on. Stem cells don't just decide on their own to proliferate or differentiate, there's all sorts of inter-cellular signaling going on so each individual cell is acting in concert with its surrounding cells, as well as the needs of the tissue, organ, and body as a whole.

Comment: Would you have some information on this signalling and regulation. I think this is the path that answers the best my question

Comment: There's so much available online using Google or Google Scholar, and searching with terms like `stem cell signaling` or `regulation of stem cell differentiation`. It's a huge area of research, so you'll need to be more specific about what exactly you're looking for. [This review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4550631/) might be a decent place to start.